# Tensorflow assign the moving_variance and moving_average of tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I have a CNN model with some batch normalization layers within it. The batchnorm layer is constructed by `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`. That model works well in basic circumstances. But a problem is that I don't know how to assign the `moving_variance` and `moving_mean` of it.

In details, as the [officail website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) describe, the batch norm layer have `variance` `mean` `scale` `offset` four parameters. The last two are tensorflow variables which I can tackle well. For the last two, even I can get them with `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))`, they are two tensors which I don't know how to assign them. In most cases these two parameters is set during the training phase.

I have also tried `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)`, I can get two tensorflow variables named `tf.Variable 'BatchNorm/moving_mean` and `tf.Variable BachNorm/moving_Variance`, althougn I can change these two variables's value with `tf.assign`, but the wierd thing is that the output of batchNorm doesn't change accordingly

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

From Tensorflow official site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm

> Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_op. For example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```